# C – Replace user-input with ******* (password)

Tags: c, user-input, password-protection

I want to write a program in C that takes **username** and **password** as input.
Is it possible to replace the password with `********` while the user is typing it in the terminal?

```
./a.out
USERNAME: someusername
PASSWORD: ********
```

If it is possible, how can that be done?

Comment: Thank you @kaylum. I think this answers my questions.